# How to exclude total number of holidays from total days in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on ticketing system application. It consists of `tickets` and `holidays` tables.

I'm showing the ticket completed days by calculating the difference between the ticket created_date and ticket closed_date.

But my requirement is to **EXCLUDE** the `holidays` from `completedInDays`. The problem here is, I don't have any common column in tickets and holidays tables to join them both.

Here is the tickets table for the sample.

[image]

And, below is the holidays table.

[image]

Now, is it possible to exclude the holidays counts from ticket completed days using SQL or Javascript?

I've tried something like this.

```
SELECT *,(DATEDIFF('2020-07-16','2020-07-08') - SUM(DATEDIFF(end_date,holiday_date))) as diff
FROM holidays
where ((holiday_date BETWEEN '2020-07-08' AND '2020-07-16')
       OR (end_date BETWEEN '2020-07-08' AND '2020-07-16'))
       AND approval_date <> '0000-00-00';
```

The query to I've used to get the ticket completed days is,

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(ticket_closedOn,ticket_createdOn) as completedInDays from tickets;
```

Comment: Have you considered counting the number of holiday rows with a date between the ticket created and closed dates, and subtracting that from your current result?

Comment: No. But I've tried something like this. ```SELECT *,(DATEDIFF('2020-07-16','2020-07-08') - SUM(DATEDIFF(end_date,holiday_date))) as diff FROM holidays where 
                                                ((holiday_date BETWEEN '2020-07-08' AND '2020-07-16') OR 
                                                (end_date BETWEEN '2020-07-08' AND '2020-07-16')) AND 
                                                approval_date <> '0000-00-00';```

Comment: But the problem am facing here is, there is no common column here. And I can't afford to make a new query just to exclude the holidays. That's why I want to have them in a same  query.

Comment: Date appears to be a common factor

Comment: Please post your original query to compute ticket completed days

Comment: Hi @AnkitBajpai, just updated the question with the query to get the ticket completed days

Answer (score 0):

The case is quite big to build a test case for writting a query. So the query shows the idea, I haven't checked it:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(ts.ticket_closedOn, ts.ticket_createdOn) total_time,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(
        GREATEST(ts.ticket_createdOn, hs.holiday_date),
        LEAST(ts.ticket_closedOn, hs.end_date)
    )) holidays,
    DATEDIFF(ts.ticket_closedOn, ts.ticket_createdOn) -
    SUM(DATEDIFF(
        GREATEST(ts.ticket_createdOn, hs.holiday_date),
        LEAST(ts.ticket_closedOn, hs.end_date)
    )) pure_time_spent
FROM
    tickets ts
LEFT JOIN
    holidays hs ON 
        hs.holiday_date BETWEEN ts.ticket_createdOn AND ts.ticket_closedOn OR
        hs.end_date BETWEEN ts.ticket_createdOn AND ts.ticket_closedOn
        AND hs.approval_date <> '0000-00-00'
GROUP BY
    ts.id, ts.ticket_createdOn, ts.ticket_closedOn
```